# matplotlib.cpp, Python 3.10 from C++

Tags: python, c++, matplotlib, visual-c++

I'm learning how to use Matplotlib from within C++ according to the [readthedocs](https://matplotlib-cpp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). I have installed Python 3.10 from scratch and copied matplotlibcpp.h from [Cryoris/matplotlib-cpp](https://github.com/Cryoris/matplotlib-cpp/blob/master/matplotlibcpp.h) into my working directory. Now, when compiling one of the examples,

```
#include <vector>
#include "matplotlibcpp.h"
namespace plt = matplotlibcpp;
int main() {
  std::vector<double> x = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  std::vector<double> y = {1, 4, 9, 16};
  // plt::plot(x, y);   // https://matplotlib-cpp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs.html
  plt::plot(x, y, "r*");  // Red stars as markers, no line
  plt::show();
```

in Visual Studio 2022 according to [pratikmahamuni1843](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp/issues/19#issuecomment-1005764776), with the required include and library folders set, I get the error message

[image]

I kind of understand the error message [C2668](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2668?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C2668)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-170), but I cannot figure out how to change the code. The issue is with the formatting string.

**Update 1:**

@hyde: Right, I figured I can set a compiler flag to ISO:C++20. That explains almost all of the errors I got with the original [lava's version](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp).

@hyde, @kiner_shah: With that compiler flag, [lava's version](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp) gives
[image] No overload, here!

@hyde: [Cryoris's version](https://github.com/Cryoris/matplotlib-cpp) still gives the same error message as above, no change.

**Update 2:**

@timonvanderberg: Modifying your suggestion to plt::plot(x, y, std::string{"r*"}), with or without the std::string, gives with
[Cryoris/matplotlib-cpp](https://github.com/Cryoris/matplotlib-cpp/blob/master/matplotlibcpp.h) [image]

**Update 3:**
Found the way to increase verbosity. With Cryoris, the error message was about an ambigous call to overloaded function. The log reads    [image] I am still learning and thus cannot decipher what it will tell me.

Comment: Try `plt::plot(x, y, std::string{"r*"});` and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: The overload you should look: https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp/blob/ef0383f1315d32e0156335e10b82e90b334f6d9f/matplotlibcpp.h#L1358.

Comment: @hyde: No, doesn't help.

Comment: @bjorn try plot<double>(x, y, "r*")

Comment: The error should tell you what overloads are the candidates. Can you expand it or something? Of not, try increasing error verbosity somehow. Or try with different compiler which gives more verbose errors.

Comment: @kiner_shah: The original version of matplotlibcpp.h itself produces 4 error messages, not including mine. Cannot show the message in the comments, though.

Comment: @Bjorn, you can edit the question and include the complete error message there.

Comment: @TimonvanderBerg: The command plot is not in my namespace, but in matplotlibcpp's one. So, we have to refer it as matplotlibcpp::plot; or plt::plot using the above namespace command, which is kind of standard.

Answer (score 0):

I understand, correct me if I'm wrong, matplotlibcpp.h contains a couple constructors, each of which falls through to the first one, that is the one finally calling plot_base. Now, the compiler cannot decide between this "fall-through to" constructor and another one further below.

```
// @brief standard plot function supporting the args (x, y, s, keywords) // line 519
// ...
template <typename VectorX, typename VectorY>
bool plot(const VectorX &x, const VectorY &y, const std::string &s = "",
          const std::map<std::string, std::string> &keywords = {}) {
  return detail::plot_base(detail::_interpreter::get().s_python_function_plot,
                           x, y, s, keywords);
}

// enable plotting of multiple triples (x, y, format) // line 1953
template <typename A, typename B, typename... Args>
bool plot(const A &a, const B &b, const std::string &format, Args... args) {
  return plot(a, b, format) && plot(args...);
}
```

I have renamed all but the first fall-through to constructor.

```
// enable plotting of multiple triples (x, y, format) // renamed, Bjorn
template <typename A, typename B, typename... Args>
bool plot1(const A &a, const B &b, const std::string &format, Args... args) {
  return plot(a, b, format) && plot(args...);
}
```

I dislike having to rename all my (standard) plot commands, and someone more knowledgeable might develop a proper solution.

Comment: Since this is an open-source repository, I recommend you raise an issue there and let the developers of this repo find appropriate solution. Renaming these functions is not a solution (or maybe it is but let the developers of that repository look into this).